# How to get myBatis(iBatis) result as Iterable. (in case of very large rows)

Tags: java, database, jdbc, mybatis

When using myBatis, I should get's very large result set from DB and do secuential operation. (such as CSV Export)

I am thinking and afraid that if return type is List, all returned data on my memory and will cause OutOfMemoryException.

So, I want to get result as a type of ResultSet or Iterable<MyObject> using myBatis.

Tell me any solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use fetchSize(refer [here](https://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html)). Based on the heap size and data size per row you can select the number of result sets to be fetched from database. Alternatively since basically you are using data export to csv, you can use spring batch which has mybatis paging item reader. Though the draw back in this item reader for each after each page an request is fired to get next page, which increase the load on your database. If you are not worried about the load you can go ahead with paging item reader. or there is simple another item reader called JdbccursorItem reader

Comment: Thank you for your response.
Finally, I came to the conclusion that I should use ResultHandler because if I can extract resultset as iterator, myBatis keep resultset after return query result.

Answer (score 5):

Starting from mybatis 3.4.1 you can return [Cursor](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/apidocs/org/apache/ibatis/cursor/Cursor.html) which is `Iterable` and can be used like this (under condition that result is ordered, see above `Cursor` API java doc for details):

MyEntityMapper.java

```
@Select({
      "SELECT *",
      "FROM my_entity",
      "ORDER BY id"
})
Cursor<MyEntity> getEntities();
```

MapperClient.java

```
MyEntityMapper mapper = session.getMapper(MyEntityMapper.class);
try (Cursor<MyEntity> entities = mapper.getEntities()) {
   for (MyEntity entity:entities) {
      // process one entity
   }
}
```